# Acessar indice de um dicionário no flask através de POST

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, postman

Como eu poderia acessar um elemento de um dicionário utilizando POST no flask?
Tenho listas para simular um BD e atráves do POST, gostaria de tentar acessar elas.

Código da função:

```
@disciplina_ofertada_app.route('/disciplina_ofertada', methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def nova_disciplina_ofertada():
        nova_disciplina_ofertada = request.get_json()
        Disciplina_ofertada.append(nova_disciplina_ofertada)
        return jsonify(Disciplina_ofertada)
```

JSON usado no POST:

```
{

    "id": 39104, 
    "id_disciplina":"Disciplina[0]['id']",
    "id_professor":"Professor[0]['id']",
    "ano":2018, "semestre": 2,
    "turma": "3C",
    "id_curso":"Curso[0]['id']",
    "data": "20/12/2019"

}
```

Com esse código ele retorna o índice como uma string e não o elemento que estou tentando acessar.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Esse modo que você está tentando fazer não é a maneira correta. Pelo visto `Disciplina` é um array. Onde está esse array? Onde você declara? Que valor você quer buscar?

Comment: Consegui resolver sim, eu queria o valor literal, para fazer uns testes. Consegui usando literal_eval.